# ASP.Net - Email to image?

Tags: asp.net

In my project I have a lot of email addresses on static sites.

Is there an algorithm to display the emails as images, so bots can't find them?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean that you have email addresses on static sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty easy to create an image from text:

http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/generate-image-from-text-using-c-or-convert-text-in-to-image-using-c/

Use a generic handler (.ashx) file to output an image.
Then link to the handler from your page..and it will show up as an image.

Comment: Can you add the explaining for the handler thing please, i never worked with this.

Comment: @Kovu - a handler is just like an aspx page.  Really.  The only difference is that it's faster because it doesn't use as many steps on the server (shorter lifecycle) and it's intended to output more than just html.